# ASP.Net MVC Invalid login attempt

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.Net, C#, MVC I get

> Invalid login attempt.

when I try to login. I commented out the email reference(s) as I only want to use the UserName and Password to login. When debugging I verify the values are correct and I also checked the values in the table to make sure there aren't any hidden characters that make the UserName or Password longer and that checks out.

Here is my code:

AccountViewModels.cs:

```
 public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        //[Required]
        //[Display(Name = "Email")]
        //[EmailAddress]
        //public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
```

Login.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @*<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>*@
              <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
              </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

AccountController.cs:

```
// POST: /Account/Login
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

I pretty much use the templates supplied by VS and changed everything according to what I found on the internet so I cannot understand what is wrong. Seems like it should work......

Comment: Have you turned on and activated ssl? a good way to tell is if your website has https:// at the start of its address by default

Comment: What is the value of `result` in your `AccountController`? Oddly enough, have you made totally sure that the credentials *are* indeed correct, rather than the logic being incorrect? Perhaps try creating another local account and logging in as that to be totally sure?

Comment: With the help of your answers I figured out the problem. While writing the code and testing and getting failures due to several circumstances when registering I had some user names which are not in the SQL table. These values are obviously saved somewhere and I need to delete them somehow so nothing like this happens again. In order to answer this question correctly can anyone provide the solution to getting rid of these rogue Usernames?

Comment: I had the same problem, I noticed that if I use different username from email, login will always invalid, so if I used the same username and email, it will log in.  I used Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

model.UserName can be compared to two fields: Email or UserName.
To define which field to use go to App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs

I think that RequireUniqueEmail is true (use Email). Changing this to false (UserName) should solve the problem.

```
    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            RequireUniqueEmail = false
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Ruard, in the IdentityConfig.cs I changed the  equireUniqueEmail to false but it didn't work. Abob78, I'm running this on my local machine and have not published it yet with the current changes. Geoff James,on the line: var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);, result is equal to "Failure". model.UserName and model.Password are both correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify how you registered your account, let see how template work.
If you register from website, then your email will be your username too, so when you log in to website and enter your email, it will succeed because the email you have to enter is the same as username.
However, if you didn't register on website and specify username differ from email, then you must enter your username.  you can view your username from database.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the RequireConfirmedAccount =true to RequireConfirmedAccount =false, in startup.cs file.

**Before**

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

**After**

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```